# MongoDB operation '.insertOne()' buffering time out after 10000

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am trying to save prodNum, prodName, and materials(array) in to mongoDB atlas.

Data should be stored in food collection in mobileContents database

prodName and materials array are another API's result.

All works fine until `.save()` is called.

Tried reinstalling Node_modules folder and MongoDB Atlas's IP Access is `0.0.0.0/0`

`MONGODBURI = mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@kyrmin.jiuin.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

```
    const mongoose = require("mongodb");
const Food = require("./models/Food");
    app.listen(3000, err => {
        if(err){
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOOSEURI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, (err, client) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }else {
                    console.log("Connected to mongoose DB");
                }
                const val = client.db("mobileContents");
                var results = [];
                app.get("/create/:prodNum", (req, res) => {
                    val.collection("food").find({prodNum: req.params.prodNum}).toArray().then(result => {
                        if(result.length === 0){
                            upload(req.params.prodNum).then((returned) => {
                                const newFood = new Food();
                                newFood.prodNum = returned.prodNum;
                                newFood.prodName = returned.prodName;
                                newFood.materials = returned.rwmat_arr;
    
                                newFood.save().then((food) => {
                                    console.log(food);
                                    res.json({message: "succesfully added in DB"});
                                }).catch((error) => {
                                    console.error(error);
                                    res.json({message: "got problem"})
                                })
                            });
                        }
                    }).catch(error => console.error(error));
                })
            })
        }
    });
```

Food() is a model that I created.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema }  = mongoose;

const foodSchema = new Schema({
    prodNum: {
        type: String,
        defualt: "-1",
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    prodName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    materials: [{
        type: String
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Food", foodSchema);
```

Comment: what is Food()?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial it's a model i created for mongoDB. I added code for Food.js in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing mongoose + mongodb native driver.

```
 const mongoose = require("mongodb");
```

should be

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

---

You need to decide whether you want to use mongodb driver or mongoose (even though mongoose runs on mongodb driver), because they manage their own separate connection.

You are currently connected with the mongodb native driver, hence when you try to use `newFood.save()`, it will time out since there are no active connections (with mongoose).

---

If you choose to use mongoose then essentially you need to remove all the mongodb codes.

E.g.

```
 const val = client.db("mobileContents"); //database should be in your mongodb connection string
```

And

```
val.collection("food").find // You should be using Model.find, where Model is the mongoose Model.
```

The above 2 line are mongodb native driver codes, you can't mix the above codes with mongoose. They don't understand each other.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: Thx! Finally found out the problem. Hope you have a good day